# centOS 7 firewallD remove direct rule

Tags: centos7, firewalld

After upgrading the system from 6.5 to 7, I started learning implementing dynamic firewall, however, I made a mistake to add the following rule

> firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -j
>   DROP

which cause the machine drop all the output to outside,

I tried to use

> firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --remove-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -j
>   DROP

to welcome everyone back.

However, after

> firewall-cmd --reload

and

> firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules

, I find this rule come back again automatically .

I even tried

> firewall-cmd --complete-reload

but no effect.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eventually I find the remove command only work at one-time due to the rules are recorded in the `direct.xml`

Thus, the solution is easy, edit the `direct.xml` and comment the corresponded lines or jsut delet them.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere do you know? I had the same thing with the `external` zone; removing ssh service didn't stay-removed until I edited the xml file (which presumably gets updated on an update...)?

Answer (score 4):

After wrestling with a stubbornly persistent redirect rule I realized through testing the following:

1. `iptables` rules DB is transient
2. `firewall-cmd --permanent` rules DB persists through reboots, rewriting `iptables` rules DB after reboot
3. `firewall-cmd --permanent --direct` rules DB stored in `/etc/firewalld/direct.xml` persists despite `firewall-cmd [--permanent] --direct --remove-rule` unless DB file is removed
4. `firewall-cmd [--permanent] --direct --query-rule` will lie about persistence of rules in `/etc/firewalld/direct.xml`

Answer (score 1):

just tried the same thing and my direct.xml was emptied after running

```
firewall-cmd --direct --remove-rule ...
```

without --permanent option.
After reload there are no direct rules which was removed.

With this option rules was back after reload.

Answer (score 1):

`firewall-cmd` [`--permanent`] `--direct --remove-rules` { `ipv4` | `ipv6` | `eb` } table chain

Comment: e.g. `firewall-cmd --direct --remove-rules ipv4 filter OUTPUT`

Answer (score -1):

No need to edict direct.xml file. 
Do a:

> `# systemctl restart firewalld`

and that will do.